# Grails No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getFile()

Tags: html, grails, groovy, uploading

I keep on getting this error message when I go to open the upload page of my Grails application:

```
No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getFile()
  is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]
  Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String),
  getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getInfo()
```

Here's my html code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        label{
            float:left;
            width:65px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <g:uploadForm action="upload">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload"/>
    </g:uploadForm>
</body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding controller class

```
package org.example.test
class AdminAccessController {
    def upload() {      
        def f = request.getFile('file')
        def allLines= f.inputStream.toCsvReader().readAll() 
    }
}
```

I've tried importing quite a ton of various libraries to fix the problem, but I haven't figured out what is going on. As you can probably tell, I will end up writing this file into a csv reader. I followed this document on the official Grails GitHub exactly: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles, but nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: Which tomcat version are you using? Looks like tomcat is throwing this error probably because it is not compatible with the version of grails you are using. Are you getting this in production environment or development environment?

Answer (score 1):

The instance of the `request` arriving to your controller is an `ApplicationHttpRequest` which has no `getFile` method.

You need to change the type of your request to `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest`.

That can be done by changing the `enctype` in your `uploadForm` to `multipart/form-data` like this:

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload"/>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Comment: isn't uploadForm is just form with enctype='multipart/form-data'? So basically this change does nothing

Comment: Maybe it is the default enctype now, but for Grails 2.3.11 it wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

Forgot about getFile(). You receive it how parameter with type MultiPartFile, so you can use its implementations:

```
params.file.getInputStream().toCsvReader().readAll()
```

Comment: `params.file` is null in this case